# How can I fix git push permission denied error showing other user name?

Tags: git, github

Other user used my PC some time ago and he also used his git account. I deleted it and everything was ok, but now I created organization on GitHub, created repo in it. I can clone it, but when I'm trying to push, I see this message:

> remote: Permission to project-name/repo-name.git denied to
> other-person-account-name. fatal: unable to access
> 'https://github.com/project-name/repo-name/': The requested URL
> returned error: 403

When I try, I get my account name. I've even generated new ssh key, nothing changed.

I can push in my other git repos.
How can it be fixed?

Comment: You can SSH key to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Check if any credential helper is used by `git config credential.helper`. If it's set, the recorded username and password are automatically used in a matched repository url. The config value could be `store` or other helper available on your operating system. If it's `store`, the username and password are stored in `~/.git-credentials` by default. You can just remove the related entry from the file. For more details, take a look at [Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

Another possible case is that `url.<base>.insteadof` or `url.<base>.pushinsteadof` is set in the config ([reference](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf)). But it's rare to use it in this case. If it's set, any url starting with `https://github.com` could be replaced by `https://${username}:${password}@github.com` when communicating with the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

> I've even generated new ssh key, nothing changed.

An SSH key is only used with an SSH URL.

If your SSH key is [properly registered](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), you can switch to an SSH URL:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git remote set-url git@github.com:orgName/repoName
git push
```